# не могу понять в чем ошибка ,и где

Tags: python, kali-linux

> File "poputka_04.09.2021.py", line 26, in 
> change_mac(options.interface, options.new_mac)
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'interface'

сам код

```py
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    
    import subprocess
    import optparse
    
    
    def get_arguments():
        parser = optparse.OptionParser()
        parser.add_option("-i", "--interface", dest="interface", help="Interface to change its MAC 
     address")
        parser.add_option("-m", "--mac", dest="new_mac", help="New MAC address")
        (options, arguments)= parser.parse_args()
        if  not options.interface:
            parser.error("[-] Please specify an interface,use --help for more info.")
        elif not options.new_mac:
            parser.error("[-] Please specify a new mac,use --help for more info.")
            return options
    
     def  change_mac(interface,new_mac):
        print("[+] Changing MAC address for " + interface + " to " + new_mac)
        subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"])
        subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "hw", "ether", new_mac])
        subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "up"])
    
    
     options = get_arguments()
     change_mac(options.interface, options.new_mac)
```

Comment: Функция get_arguments ничего не возвращает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
#!usr/bin/env python
import optparse
import subprocess
import re

def get_arguments():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-i", "--interface", dest="interface", help="Interface to change its MAC address")
    parser.add_option("-m", "--mac", dest="new_mac", help="New MAC address")
    (options, arguments) = parser.parse_args()
    if not options.interface:
        parser.error("[-] Please specify an interface, use --help for more info.")
    elif not options.new_mac:
        parser.error("[-] Please specify a new mac, use --help for more info.")
    return options
   
def change_mac(interface, new_mac):
    print("[+] Changing MAC address for " + interface + " to " + new_mac)
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"])
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "hw", "ether", new_mac])
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "up"])
   
def get_current_mac(interface):
    ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", interface])
    mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)
    if mac_address_search_result:
        return mac_address_search_result.group(0)
    else:
        print("[-] Could not read MAC address.")

options = get_arguments()

current_mac = get_current_mac(options.interface)
print("Current MAC = " + str(current_mac))

change_mac(options.interface, options.new_mac)

current_mac = get_current_mac(options.interface)
if current_mac == options.new_mac:
    print("[+] MAC address was successfully changed to " + current_mac)
else:
    print("[-] MAC address did not get changed.")
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).